# Installing docker on parrot os

Tags: docker, parrot-os

I am new to Linux and using Parrot Os (Home Edition). I am trying to install Docker on the same. But have been unable to do so.

This is for running MySQL and I also think that it will be useful to me later. I tried installing docker using APT package manager as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install docker
```

The installation completes but after that it when i try to start the service, it says

```
Failed to start docker.service: Unit docker.service not found.
```

Since I am an newbie, please give detailed answer or place links so that i can read it myself?
Thanks.

Comment: Try to install docker using script as mentioned here https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#install-using-the-convenience-script Just give it a try.

Comment: @mchawre It downloaded the script but when i ran it, it said `# Executing docker install script, commit: 36b78b2

Either your platform is not easily detectable or is not supported by this
installer script.
Please visit the following URL for more detailed installation instructions:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just confirm the docker installation after `sudo apt-get install docker` is successful.

From the error, it seems `docker.service` file is not created after installation.

Try to create the `docker.service` file manually. Refer [this](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/#manually-create-the-systemd-unit-files).

You probably need to create `/etc/systemd/system/docker.socket` file with [these](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/contrib/init/systemd/docker.socket) contents. And `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service` file with [these](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/contrib/init/systemd/docker.service) contents.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am sorry but it didn't work. Could something have gone wrong during installation? Because there was no installation method for Parrot Os (It is Debian-like but so is Ubuntu. And there were methods to install docker on ubuntu.) I am sorry, but  I am a noob, so I don't know about all this.

Comment: Found this doc https://www.hiroom2.com/2017/09/24/parrotsec-3-8-docker-engine-en/ can you give it a try.

Answer (score 9):

You can easily install **docker** with the following command.

```
┌─[user@parrot-virtual]─[~/Desktop]
└──╼ $sudo apt install docker.io
```

After successful installation..

```
┌─[user@parrot-virtual]─[~/Desktop]
└──╼ $docker
        
 Usage:  docker [OPTIONS] COMMAND
        
        A self-sufficient runtime for containers
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your debian version number then cross reference that to their names (i.e wheezy, etc.).

then go to [docker ce downloads](https://download.docker.com) navigate to 
`linux -> debian -> dists -> (your debian version name)` and download the version you want

Now, install it with 
`sudo dpkg -i {your path to the download .deb file}`

> PS: `sudo apt-get install docker` doesn't install docker for me anymore. It install wmdocker which seems to be different.

**Additional info**

here is the result of my `uname -a`

`Linux parrot 5.4.0-4parrot1-amd64 #1 SMP Parrot 5.4.19-4parrot1 (2020-02-27) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

You can test if it works with
`sudo docker run hello-world`

Answer (score 0):

```
┌─[root@parrot]─[/home/harry]
└──╼ #sudo apt install docker.io
```

This command will install docker instead of "apt install docker-ce".

Answer (score 0):

first fix all broken packages in your apt repo using `sudo apt --fix-broken install` then `sudo apt update` then run `sudo apt install docker.io`

Answer (score 0):

never use apt-get on parrot. parrot uses apt. i used apt-get the first time i used parrot and ended up having to completley reinstall parrot.

```
 $sudo apt install docker.io
```

this  works i just installed it and tried it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please explain how this can address the question